# enum operators (+,-,*,/) in c

Tags: c, enums

I want to make an enum that contains operations (+,-/,*).
something like that

`enum operators{plus="+",minus="-",multy="*",div="/"};`

or something like the above.

I want to compare it with a string for example (when input="+"):

```
enum operators op;
scanf("%s",input);
  if(strcmp(input,op.plus)==0 ) // compiler error here 
      printf("ok");
```

Any ideas will be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read your edit, answered below.

Answer (score 4):

`enums` are ints and character constants are also ints in C, so you could do it this way:

```
enum operators { plus = '+', minus = '-', mult = '*', div = '/' };
```

If you have a string (char array) named `input`, you can do your test like this:

```
if (input[0] == plus)
    printf("ok");
```

You're more likely to use it in a switch statement:

```
switch (input[0]) {
case plus:
    // do something
    break;
case minus:
    // do something
    break;
```

etc.

Comment: interesting, but how can i compare it with a string something like this  enum operators op;
        scanf("%s",input);
        if(strcmp(input,op.plus)==0 ){
            printf("\nok");  

when input="+";

Comment: @csgk - Can you read in a `char`?, if so then you can simply test that your `input_value == '+';` (et. al.).  Your strcmp idea also works, just as you described it.  Its really up to you.

Comment: I read it as char and doesn't work with the above code i get compiler error< error: request for member ‘plus’ in something not a structure or union>....? input=='+' it is not work you will get compiler warning< warning: comparison between pointer and integer> a have try it, and and of course input=="+" doesn't work.

Comment: @csgk - If you want to use strings, then you have to use them all around, i.e. instead of an enum to define type of operation, use a struct with members of strings (i.e. char add[2]={"+"}; etc), then when you `scanf("%s",input)`,  your `strcmp(input, add);` will == 0. (if user input a "+")

Answer (score 1):

`enum` is a fancy name for an integer type.  `"+"` is a string, not an integer.

Use:

```
enum operators { plus = '+', minus = '-', multy = '*', div = '/' };
```

Alternatively, you could simply use:

```
enum operators { plus, minus, multy, div };
```

The values will be distinct, but the numbering will start at 0.

Comment: +1 for pointing our difference between "+" and '+'.  I cannot count the times I have been caught on that.

Answer (score 0):

The notation you are using (i.e. op.plus) is not correct for enum.  It would be for `struct` notation.

However, You could do something like this:
(***note***, I am not using strings, I am using `char` & `int` instead, they are easier to integrate later in the `switch()` statement.)

#include

```
enum operator {
    plus = '+', //add == 43
    minus = '-', //minus == 45
    mult = '*', //mult == 42
    divi = '/', //div == 47
};



int main(void)
{
    int a, b;
    char op;

    printf("enter \"+\", \"-\", \"*\" or \"/\"\n");
    scanf("%c", &op);
    printf("enter 2 integer values separated by a space, <return>\n");
    scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);
    switch(op) {
        case plus:
            printf("%d + %d == %d\n", a, b, a+b);
            break;
        case minus:
            printf("%d - %d == %d\n", a, b, a-b);
            break;
        case mult:
            printf("%d * %d == %d\n", a, b, a*b);
            break;
        case divi:
            printf("%d / %d == %d\n", a, b, a/b);
            break;
    }
    getchar();
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Note, that because this does *integer* math, things like 5/2 will == 2, not 2.5